# Template method in C++ to assign wchar_t* or char* to array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have the following problem. I have a template method that accepts an array of normal or `long char*` as the following:

```
template <class myType>
static void createArray(const myType* (&MyArray)[10])
```

Now I want to assign values to this array depending on the `myType` variable that can be either `char*` or `wchar_t`. I created small method that tells me wether `myType` is long or not so that I can assign the type, like this:

```
MyArray[1] =  ( MyTemplate<myType>::isWide()) ? L"-1" : "-1";
```

Unfortunately I always get an error that I cannot assign `wchar_t` to `char` array or vice versa.
I cannot use string class.
Any ideas if this is possible?
Thank you!

Comment: This operator is evaluated at runtime not at compile time, hence the error.

Comment: I think, the solution is to use statically inited arrays instead of C strings

Comment: `static myType[] s1 = { '-', '1', 0 };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *at compile time*, there's a type mismatch. Here's the trick you want:

```
template <typename t>
struct x {
    static t *c;
};

template<>
char *x<char>::c = "-1";
template<>
wchar_t *x<wchar_t>::c = L"-1";
```